# How to denormalize data with primary and secondary key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort this normalized data set into orders with items starting at `set_no = 0`, `line_no = 0`.

With this function all the items are binned correctly, but `set_no` and `line_no` aren't updated.

```
let data = JSON.parse('[{"header":{"set_no":0},"line":{"line_no":2},"order":{"cart_id":"X1"}},{"header":{"set_no":4},"line":{"line_no":6},"order":{"cart_id":"X2"}},{"header":{"set_no":8},"line":{"line_no":10},"order":{"cart_id":"X1"}}]');

function denormalizeData(data) {

  let result = Object.values(                 // Index keys, starting with 0
      data.reduce((r, { order }, i, arr) => { // Push items to order, matching on unique cart_id
      let item = arr[i];
      r[order.cart_id] = (r[order.cart_id] || { order, items: [] });
      r[order.cart_id].items.push(item);
      return r;
    }, {})
  );

  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

}

denormalizeData(data);
```

For example, in this case the goal would be to sort and update lines 0 and 1 for set 0, and line 0 for set 1.

How would I start at `set_no = 0` and `line_no = 0` when setting the new array and increment each accordingly when pushing new indices?

Expected output

```
[  
   {  
      "order":{  
         "cart_id":"X1"
      },
      "items":[  
         {  
            "header":{  
               "set_no":0
            },
            "line":{  
               "line_no":0
            }
         },
         {  
            "header":{  
               "set_no":0
            },
            "line":{  
               "line_no":1
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "order":{  
         "cart_id":"X2"
      },
      "items":[  
         {  
            "header":{  
               "set_no":1
            },
            "line":{  
               "line_no":0
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Adding expected output would greatly help people who are trying to answer this question.

Comment: Now updated....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be the answer:

```js
function denormalizeData(data) {

    let result = Object.values(                 // Index keys, starting with 0
        data.reduce((r, {order}, i, arr) => { // Push items to order, matching on unique cart_id
            let {header, line} = arr[i];
            let item = {header, line};
            r[order.cart_id] = (r[order.cart_id] || {order, items: []});
            r[order.cart_id].items.push(item);
            item.header.set_no = Object.keys(r).indexOf(order.cart_id);
            item.line.line_no = r[order.cart_id].items.length - 1;
            return r;
        }, {})
    );

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
}

denormalizeData(data);
```

As you can see, `line_no` is really a number of items minus one in current order, so I use `items.length - 1` there.

But `set_no` is a bit more complex, because order chunks can come unordered, that's why I get index of current order (some magic with object keys as this is not an array, but an object).

Also, I have removed stray `order` structure from output to match your example.

Comment: This is really good! I just changed a couple lines to `let item = arr[i]; delete arr[i]['order'];` since the in use `data` object is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Also, thank you for teaching me `console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));` :)

Comment: No probs. Just make sure you won't use that in production as spaces take too much, ahem, space.

Comment: @alx, you can use this 
``` 
r[order.cart_id].items.push({header:{set_no: Object.keys(r).indexOf(order.cart_id)}, line:{line_no: r[order.cart_id].items.length}});
```

Comment: @GhoulAhmed thanks for your tip. I tried to avoid heavy code modifications to allow original author easily see the changes.